# How to move the turtle where I want to go

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

So I'm trying to complete this question on my programming course, and it involves drawing stuff with the turtle.
Basically, I'm trying to draw a city skyline, so the program needs to read multiple inputs from the user on one line (the heights of the buildings). I can get it to draw a building, but it only uses the last y-value.

```
from turtle import *
h = input("Heights: ")
y = h.split()
nxc = -200

#Code for the background

fillcolor("darkslategray")
for i in y:
  for i in y:
    nyc = i
  pencolor("black")
  pendown()
  begin_fill()
  goto(nxc, nyc)
  right(90)
  forward(20)
  right(90)
  forward(nyc)
  right(90)
  forward(20)
  right(90)
  forward(nyc)
  end_fill()
  nxc = nxc + 20
```

Help please!

Here's a picture:
[Description of the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsWbA.png)
[Some of the specifics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suQ7M.png)

Comment: Why do you have `for i in y:` twice? Is there a need to loop through `y` two times?

Comment: Why are you iterating `for i in y` twice in a row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take out your second `for` loop:

```
from turtle import *
h = input("Heights: ")
y = h.split()
nxc = -200

#Code for the background

fillcolor("darkslategray")
for i in y:
  nyc = i
  pencolor("black")
  pendown()
  begin_fill()
  goto(nxc, nyc)
  right(90)
  forward(20)
  right(90)
  forward(nyc)
  right(90)
  forward(20)
  right(90)
  forward(nyc)
  end_fill()
  nxc = nxc + 20
```

This second loop will always reach the end, updating `nyc` each time, before it exits. Thus, for every iteration, `nyc` will advance to the final value before Python gets to your drawing code.